# WebRTC C# video stream not start until codec is changed

Tags: c#, uwp, webrtc

I'm working on a videochat UWP application and I've discovered [Chatterbox](https://github.com/webrtc-uwp/ChatterBox) on GitHub which seems a good solution.

Now I'm figuring out an issue: sometimes the video stream doesn't start and I need to switch the selected video codec.

By default there are two working video codec, VP8 and H264, both of these work well but when I reinstall the UWP I face with that problem, video won't start until the codec is switched. This problem seems not to depend on which is the default codec, sometimes it shows with H264 as default and sometimes with VP8 as default.

I'm triyng to solve this debugging the application and triyng to discover where the error is and how it is generated, but until now I wasn't been able to find it.

Is there someone which has already faced a similar problem or has some suggestions to give to me in order to solve this annoying problem?

Comment: Since you didn't provide any code, did we just test the ChatterBox project can reproduce your issue?

Comment: IFinally I've solved this issue, if your're interested you will find a detailed explanation in the answer.
The bug can be reproduced simply closing the application and reopening it, to avoid the bug you need to visit the settings page before starting a video call .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've solved this issue, here I will try to explain the procedure which I've adopted, it's not very elegant but it works.

**Reproduce the bug:**

In order to reproduce this bug you simply need to start a video call without having visited the settings page; if this page has been navigated close the application and start it again, then open a video call without navigating to settings.

**Bug explaination:**

The bug was caused by settings loading at the application startup, some configurations have a default value, such has signalingServerAdress and SignalingServerPort; other configuration are dinamically and asynchronously loaded (eg. video and audio codecs) because they depend on hardware capabilities.
When the UWP is started asynchronously configurations aren't correctly loaded and the Context object is not fully polulated.
This incomplete object causes the video stream not to start when the sdp offer is sent to the remote peer.

**Bug solution (not very elegant):**

I've solve the bug forcing the application to show setting page, so all the configuration is loaded and the user must save it in order to navigate to contacts page.

I've modified **ContactsView.xaml.cs** adding a boolean `_isFirstNavigation = true`, then I've invoked `ShowSettings` command to diplay setting page.

Here the whole method I've modified:

```
private void ContactsView_DataContextChanged(FrameworkElement sender, 
DataContextChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            var viewModel = DataContext as ContactsViewModel;
            if (viewModel == null) return;
            viewModel.RingtoneElement = RingtoneElement;



            //adding the following if block solved the bug
            if (_isFirstNavigation)
            {
                viewModel.ShowSettings.Execute(null);
                _isFirstNavigation = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Looks like a bug in the ChatterBox project. You should submit it as an issue on github.